# FileNotFound error when trying to move files with the Shutil Python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, shutil

I wrote the following code to recognize and organize gif and image files. `cdir` refers to the directory the program is supposed to organize. When it is executed, it should create folders 'Gifs' and 'Images' in the same directory.

```
import shutil, os

gifext = ['.gif', 'gifv']
picext = ['.png', '.jpg']

for file in files:
   if file.endswith(tuple(gifext)):
       if not os.path.exists(cdir+'\Gifs'):
           os.makedirs(cdir + '\Gifs')
       shutil.move(cdir + file, cdir + '\Gifs')

   elif file.endswith(tuple(picext)):
       if not os.path.exists(cdir+'\Images'):
           os.makedirs(cdir + '\Images')
       shutil.move(cdir + file, cdir + '\Images')
```

The directory contains the files: FIRST.gif, SECOND.gif and THIRD.jpg

But I get the following error:

```
  File "test.py", line 16
    shutil.move(cdir + file, cdir + '\Gifs')
  File "C:\Users\stavr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 552, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\Users\stavr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 251, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\stavr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 114, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\stavr\\Desktop\\testFIRST.gif'
```

Comment: This question doesn't deserve a downvote. Yeah, the issue at hand is somewhat trivial to seasoned Pythonistas. But the *question* is nothing short of **exemplary**: Clear problem statement, expected results / actual results, full, self contained and executable code, full traceback.

Comment: Thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`files` contains only the names of the files in a directory. `cdir` doesn't have a backslash at the end, so, when you concatenate `cdir` with an element of `files` you get a potentially invalid path:

```
"C:\stuff\my\path" + "file_name.png"
# equals
"C:\stuff\my\pathfile_name.png"
```

The latter is obviously not what you wanted, so you should add that backslash to `cdir` somehow, maybe like this:

```
if not cdir.endswith("\\"):
    cdir += "\\"
```

Comment: `cdir.endswith(os.sep):` is even better, or suggest the use of `os.path.join` and raw strings.

Answer (score 1):

Your file path is incorrect. There's a path separator missing.

```
shutil.move(os.path.join(cdir, file), os.path.join(cdir, 'Gifs'))
```

Comment: Instead of concatenating paths by hand, one should use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) instead. This would have prevented this error in the first place, and also results in portable code.

Answer (score 0):

Following the error report there is a "\" missing in the path between your directory "test" und the file "FIRST.gif":

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\stavr\\Desktop\\testFIRST.gif'
```

You can resolve this by adding "\" when you put in the path like this:

```
Enter path to the directory: C:\Users\stavr\Desktop\test\
```

OR

replace:

```
shutil.move(cdir + file, cdir + '\Gifs')
```

by:

```
shutil.move(os.getcwd() + '/' + file, cdir + '\Gifs')
```

By the way:
I think here's a "." missing before "gifv"

```
gifext = ['.gif', 'gifv']
```